# Hibernate updatable=false if it is not null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to create a column like firstSeenVersion and this field can be null. But with time, it can be updated.

My purpose is; set it first-time, if it's not null. Then don't touch it anymore.

```
MyEntity
{
    @Column(name = "first_seen_version", updatable = false)
    private String firstSeenVersion;
}
```

So I wonder that is there an easy way in hibernate/JPA to handle it?

Example Scenario:

```
New-Data    Persistent-Data
null        null
V1          V1  -> Update it because it's null.
V2          V1  -> Because no-updatable anymore
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to handle this out of the box. You can do this by using a database trigger or just hiding access to the field and manage the details in `@PreUpdate`/`@PrePersist` listeners within the entity class.